# use a fade out transition, it works but then the whole page goes white

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fade

i would use a simple

```
<div class="answer1"> </div>
```

CSS

```
.answer1{
  width: 330px; 
  height: 300px;
  z-index:100;
  background-image: url('../images/answer1.png'); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top:250px;
  left: 260px;
  cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;
}
```

and then my transition

```
$('.answer1').click(function(){
  transition("#question2","push-left");
});
```

This makes the link work but after a second the page goes white, why does this happen?

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Where is the `transition` function declared?

Comment: It pushes left, which works but then does not stay loaded